lru-cache vs node-cache vs redis, which one is better?
I have a project where I previously used redis for performance reasons. Because in my app the get / set ratio is too large and most requests are for getting some data from the database. Since db operations takes time, I decided to use redis as a cache for performance reasons.
Anyways, now I am rewriting the codebase and considering caching alternatives. The candidates are:

lru-cache: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lru-cache &
node-cache: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache

I searched about it and found out no real discussion on the internet regarding this topic (there are some on comparison for node-cache but none for lru-cache).
I want to hear others opinions about for my use case which solution can be better. I am concerned that in limited memory conditions, node-cache / lru-cache would eat out the memory from main app or affect my apps performance. Currently I use free Redis services included with hosting (30MB) that keeps Redis memory separate. However, the advantage is that with node-cache, you don't need to install Redis for caching and get cached items over network which in theory should result in a higher latency.
Note: The average data size for for get operations is not that large. Maybe 500kb at max and ~200kb on average? Also, I am using Heroku Basic dynos for hosting which has 512MB memory. My last 24hr peak traffic was 99rps (requests per second) with the average being 50-70rps. The peak memory consumption during this time was ~170MB.
